# neo4j Milestone 2.3.0 M3 Load CSV error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

since the upgrade to version Neo4j 2.3.0 M3
while trying to run an existing process of data loading,
i'm getting the error:

```
Expected line to be a property container
```

on M2 it runs ok

Comment: please provide a) exact Cypher command your using and b) a snippet of your csv to reproduce that error.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster can i send you privately the csv and the script?